# Fill in db field based on conditional input

Tags: javascript

I have 4 input fields:

- Descrition (hidden)
- Promo1
- Promo2
- Promo3

The user can only fill in one of the three Promo fields.

I managed this part with radio buttons, so the promos fields display according to the radio checked.

How can I populate the Description with the same data from the Promo (1, 2 or 3) based on the radio button checked?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, why this is labeled both RoR and JavaScript or how you're accomplishing this (is AJAX involved? ) Please try to elaborate more if you expect to get any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to set the value of the description input to the value of the promo input,   you may use the 'keyup' javascript event to set the value of this field. Something like this in CoffeeScript:

```
$('.promo-inputs').on keyup: ->
    $('#description-input').val($(this).val())
```

See http://api.jquery.com/keyup/